# Unknown error appears when adding corner styling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am adding styling to corners of elements dynamically using the jQuery Corners plugin and up until now it's been working fine, but now I'm getting an unknown error popping up on just a couple of elements.
The error:[image]

(I changed the HTML to what the JS expects it to be and this still happens)

Any ideas what's happening? Help appreciated.

Comment: What is the jQuery corners plugin?

Comment: Can be found here: [jQuery Corners](http://jquery.malsup.com/corner/)

Comment: Well, logic would dictate that if it was previously working, and now it is not, you need to ask yourself, what changed?

Comment: New jquery version? new pluging version? changing the html around?

Comment: What does `corners()` and `uncorners()` do?

Comment: Some of the HTML has been changed but I've checked through that and it shouldn't be making a difference.

Comment: Has your web browser version changed?

Comment: `corners()` and `uncorners()` are the functions that style or destyle the corners

Comment: Might be worth it to try to go back to the old html and see if it starts working again. It's possible something unintentionally got removed this plugin might need

Comment: @CaolanEvans: Could you show us those functions?  Maybe that's the error's source?

Comment: Can you maybe make us a demo showing the issue?  Possibly on http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe because button `#togdevs` innerhtml is nothing? the button doesnt have any html in it, so maybe it can't aplly corners on nothing

Comment: Don't know why but this appears to have worked: I added some text to it and it worked.